# 'The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error' after update Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

After an update of windows, I get the error message during build in one of the projects.
I have tried to update all third party references without success.

Google betrays me with nothing to use to solve the problem

Someone who can give a clue what happened?

Comment: Had the same issue, I had to run `msbuild` with `-verbosity:diag` commandline option and then it gave a helpful error message. One package reference was missing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the cause of the error in a com library that has remained after some experiment before.
Library "MSHTML" (COM component)

When I removed the reference, the builde worked again

Comment: I am having the same error. Removed  Microsoft.mshtml.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies but still getting the same error. Did you mean something other than what I did?

Comment: My conclusion was that an update of windows seems to have removed mshtml.dll from my computer. When my project in vs had the dll as a reference, I received the error message. It appeared in Solution Explorer -> References where it was marked in red. Since I no longer use mshtml.dll in my project, I was able to delete the reference in Solution Explorer (Rightclick -> delete)

Comment: I had this issue, unfortunately wasn't able to ditch the reference.
A temporal workaround is to build your own tlbimp substitute of the dll:
`tlbimp C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb  /namespace:mshtml`