# Visual Studio 2019 return error when debug "The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 will return this error when debug :-

```
"The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error"Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4181 The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error. C:\b\tree\master\cloud\src\Helper Utilities\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.HelperUtilities\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.HelperUtilities.sln   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   2827
```

Any advice please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64486762/17034

Comment: @HansPassant not sure that i need to do exactly  ? i already read the post before

Comment: @HansPassant also in my case i do not have any reference to MSHTML library